# Editing title of question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, title, quality-filter

When creating a question I can't put the word `problem` in the title. I actually can when editing the title of a question. Is this a bug?

Comment: Word filters for titles are site-specific; what site are you referring to? E.g., on Math it's never a problem to put problem in the title.

Comment: @Thursday Unix & Linux

Comment: Can you link to the question you were editing? Thanks.

Comment: @AnnaLear http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/59227

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're a wizard, indeed.

Comment: @William only if I can fix it without being a dev... ;)

Comment: To be clear, does your "creating a question" experience refer to Unix&Linux or another site (e.g. Stack Overflow)?

Comment: @Thursday To all sites actually..

Comment: "Problem" isn't blocked on all sites. On sites where it is, it is currently blocked for editors in the same manner that it is blocked for authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We aren't blocking any words in titles on Unix & Linux.

Comment: But OP claims it's blocked when asking a new question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It shouldn't be. Gonna need to see a screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The word `problem` is blocked on all sites I have an account on, apparently not on Unix & Linux.